# Jquery - Duplicate DropDown without copying set value

Tags: jquery, duplicates, row, default

I have the following code which duplicates a form row including the dropdown lists and input fields. This code which works perfectly, apart from one slight issue.

**http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/6/**

What ever values are entered into the first row are duplicated to the new rows.

Is there anyway to duplicate the row, but have the values of the inputs and drop downs on the new row be default. ie: no item selected in the drop down and the inputs empty.

I have tried chaging this:

```
$newRow.find('#BoxName').val($("#TemplateRow").find('#BoxName').val());
            $newRow.find('#BoxComparison').val($("#TemplateRow").find('#BoxComparison').val());
            $newRow.find('#BoxVal').val($("#TemplateRow").find('#BoxVal').val());
```

To this:

```
 $newRow.find('#BoxName').val($("#TemplateRow").find('#BoxName').val(''));
        $newRow.find('#BoxComparison').val($("#TemplateRow").find('#BoxComparison').val(''));
        $newRow.find('#BoxVal').val($("#TemplateRow").find('#BoxVal').val(''));
```

That resulted in the new being defaulted, but also the first row !

Any ideas how I can do this ?

Comment: so you want to duplicate the rows with the first values ?

Comment: i don't understand your question properly. can you please be more specific ?

Comment: the solution you mention should actually work: you clone your row and reset the values. Isn't this what you mean to do? http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/7/

Comment: @Danilo - that seems to work fine.. why didn't it work for me ! ?!

Comment: @FrebinFrancis - I want to clone the first row, but not any values that have been selected in it.

Comment: @Rocket what about textbox ?

Comment: @Rocket check the updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/8/

Comment: @Danilo - If you submit this as an answer I'll accept it. Works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code you can clone the row and reset the field values:

```
  var $newRow = $('#TemplateRow').clone(true).removeAttr('id');
  $newRow.find('#BoxName').val('');
  $newRow.find('#BoxComparison').val('');
  $newRow.find('#BoxVal').val('');    
  $newRow.find('input[name="DeleteBoxRow"]').prop('checked', false); //Example: search by name
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kvesskv/9/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store the row in a variable when the page loads, something like:

```
    newRow = "<tr>" + $("#TemplateRow").html() + "</tr>";
```

Then all you need do in your click function is add that newRow before the button like you're already doing.

Comment: Sorry can you explain this a little further.. I don't understand !

Comment: Right now you're handling everything within the click event.  You're cloning the row, attempting to reset the values, and placing this cloned row in your table.

Instead, I'm suggesting storing the row in a variable from the start outside of any events.  This variable will remain unchanged, and you can insert it into the table whenever the button is clicked, instead of cloning a table from the row.

Comment: Alternately, you could just explicitly create a string with all of the html written out, but I think accessing the existing html is a little more elegant.  I could create a bin for you if you'd like to see it in action...